# NUMBERS- write text based on two checkboxes

Tags: numbers

I would like to have a function tied to two checkboxes.

1. checkbox.....YES - NO
2. checkbox.....YES - NO

Result in a cell based on the combination:

1).................2).........output in a separate cell

yes..............yes........text 1

yes..............no.........text 2

no...............yes.........text 3

no...............no..........text 4

Could you please give me a recommendation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that first checkbox is in column B and second checkbox in column C, both on row #2 following formula delivers desired result:

```
=IFS(AND(B2,C2),"text1", AND(B2, NOT(C2)), "text2", AND(NOT(B2), C2), "text3", AND(NOT(B2), NOT(C2)), "text4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it.
I used three extra columns.

E2...IF(B2=TRUE;"1";"0")

F2...IF(C2=TRUE;"2";"0")

F3...E2+F2... so the result can be 0;1;3 and it is in G2

Function:
IF(G2=1; "text 1";IF(G2=2; "text 2"; "text 3"))